# How can people be dying of starvation when the markets and storage barns are full of food?

Tags: banished

I've got a really strange occurrence. I've got a lot of food- so much food that I've got to take people off food production or I can't build new storage barns fast enough to hold my food excesses. But my population are still dying of starvation. I've built some markets and they too are full of food. Why on earth are people dying of starvation when I've got so much food?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Having Food" is not synonymous with "Being able to **Eat** food".

If you have plenty of surplus, and still people dying to starvation, the problem likely exists within your supply chain. In my experience, this usually means people are involved in pathing very long distances, such that they starve on their way home to eat.

Use the info panel to follow starving citizens. Where are they going? Where are they coming from? I've seen at more than one Let's Play where folks have mistakenly designated buildings far away, long before a sane path to reach them exists -- the end result was people walking towards the structure, giving up 75% of the way there when hunger kicked in, starting back, and dying before they reached their homes.

Comment: I built a distributed network- virtually everybody in my society lives right next to a gatherer/hunter in densely-forested area with storage barn also right next to them for exactly this reason. You seem to be right though- every time I assign some populace to build things, there's no slack housing, and there's a bunch of people suddenly living a long way from their jobs.

Comment: I also seem to find that sometimes you get people living alone, which isn't ideal when it comes to determining how much housing you need and where.

Comment: I think I solved at least part of the problem- turns out that a bunch of my local storage barns were overflowing with leather, so they had nowhere to put the food. But the game didn't warn me because the total space wasn't running out.

Comment: Bridges, and builders wanting to work on both sides of them, can be a big source of these long walks.